# Assigning colours to flags picking the corresponding colour from a DF

Tags: r, dataframe, plot

I would like to assign specific colours (`C`) to specific flags (`POP`) in my plot. I tried

```
PC <- data.frame(POP = c("A", "C", "C", "B"), 
                 X = c(0.1,0.2,0.3,0.4), 
                 Y = c(0.1,0.2,0.3,0.4))

COLS <- data.frame(C = c("red", "grey", "brown"), 
                   P = c("A", "B","C"))

plot(PC$X, PC$Y, col = COLS$C[which(COLS$P == PC$POP)])
```

but get the following errors

```
 Warning messages:
  1: In `==.default`(COLS$P, PC$POP): longer object length is not a multiple of shorter object length
  2: In is.na(e1) | is.na(e2): longer object length is not a multiple of shorter object length
```

and colours in the resulting plot are not correct.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put `col = COLS$C[match(PC$POP, COLS$P)]` instead. See `?match` for its use.

You can't safely apply `"=="` to two vectors of different lengths. The logic is as same as your adding two vectors of different length. Recycling rule applies. This rule is useful in some applications, but it is your responsibility to make it do the right thing / generate the desired result.

Also, you need `stringsAsFactors = FALSE` in `data.frame()` call to avoid your colour variables (strings) being coded as factors (integers).